# Shell Script for file operation

Tags: shell, unix

I have a script

```
awk -F, '$4!~/ABCDEF/{print $0}' File_Name.csv>New_File_Name.csv
```

This is a script , which deletes the entire row in a csv file if a cell in 19 th (D - column in csv) column consists of ABCDEF . 
Here i am giving file name and new file name manually . I have to pick all the files in a directory and then export that file to another directory . How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this script in the directory that contains all the `*csv` files:

```
for f in *.csv; do
   awk -F, '!($4 ~ /ABCDEF/)' "$f" > "/dest/dir/$f"
done
```

Comment: I am getting this error , $ ./Check.sh
./Check.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/Check.sh: line 1: `for f in *.csv; do

Comment: I am using cygwin , hope thats the issue . Let me try in linux environment itself

Comment: Having trouble in my VM , will try that and let you know .

Comment: I tried using dummy CSV , i am getting perfect output . But , if i use my original file the files are generated with empty datas

Comment: That means dummy CSV and original file have some different structure. If you upload a sample of original file on pastebin.com then I can take a look.

Comment: Before that i need one more favour . I have a CSV file , i want to remove comma at the end of each file . Hoe can i do that ?

Comment: You can use `sed -i.bak 's/[,[:blank:]]*$//' file.csv`

Comment: No hope i coulding do that , empty file is generated

Comment: I tried using this command 
awk '{gsub(/,$/,""); print}' Comma.csv > Comma1.csv , eventhough empty file is generated

Comment: No i have again same status . I am running in centos , its fine . If i run it in red hat , i am getting error

Comment: I cannot keep commenting on imaginary issues. Provide a sample of input file in question with your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Set proper values for `directory` and `another_directory`, then try this:

```
for fname in $directory/*.csv; do awk -F, '$4!~/ABCDEF/{print $0}' $fname > $another_directory/`basename $fname`; done
```

You can also put it into a script file (let it be `script.sh`) like this:

```
directory=$1
another_directory=$2
for fname in $directory/*.csv; do awk -F, '$4!~/ABCDEF/{print $0}' $fname > $another_directory/`basename $fname`; done
```

Make it executable and invoke like this:

```
./script.sh path_to_source_directory path_to_destination_directory
```

Comment: Getting this error line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @JimMacaulay That sounds strange, because there are only 3 lines in the file. I created two directories, empty `*.csv` file in one of them and the script worked without any errors on that directories.